# Cplex Random number (c++)

Tags: c++, random, cplex

I did a random number before in c++ which works but when I try with CPLEX it doesn't work at all.

I would like to know how to do random in cplex

The way I do random in c++ :

```
int t = (rand() % 10) +1 ;
```

I try this:

```
int main() {
srand(time(0));
IloEnv env; 
IloInt j;
IloModel model(env); 
IloInt dt = (rand() % 10) +1 ;
if(j > dt){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Care to show what you tried that *doesn't* work?

Comment: It would be great if you talked about exactly why you need random numbers in CPLEX...or for that matter, why you would ever use random input to a MIP solver.

Comment: Not enough information to answer the question. The only thing that comes to mind here is that IloInt is a long and not an int but I don't know if that's relevant without more info. Also, you might want to fix your seed while you're developing your code.

Also @AndrewMao, a couple of possibilities: scenario generation for stochastic programs or integer programming guided local search with randomized neighborhoods.

Answer (score 0):

Interactive programming like random number generation is not possible in CPLEX, as Andrew commented above. Though you can use Java,C or other libraries with CPLEX for this purpose. If you are using OPL with CPLEX, then one way of generating random number is:

```
int mySeed;
execute{
var now = new Date();
mySeed = Opl.srand(Math.round(now.getTime()/1000));
}   
int tabSize = 60;
int myRandTab[i in 1..20] = 1 + rand(tabSize);
```